# Select query which give those rows having two or more than two non-zero values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with 8 columns (id,user,a,b,c,d,e,f)
in which I have a list of distinct users with (0 through 9) values in columns like this:

```
Id  User    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   0001    0   1   0   0   0   0
2   0002    0   5   8   4   6   5
3   0003    0   0   0   0   0   5
4   0004    2   6   4   5   4   1
5   0005    1   0   0   0   0   0
6   0006    7   6   5   4   0   9
7   0007    4   0   0   0   0   8]
```

I want a MySQL select query which gives a list of those users having two or more than two non-zero values.
So the query should return record id (2,4,6,7). Thanks

Comment: Wasn't this question asked a few days ago? Same class?

Comment: This kind of problem is often indicative of poor design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way to do so

```
select *
from t
where
( 
  (A <> 0 )+
  (B <> 0) +
  (C <> 0 )+
  (D <> 0 )+
  (E <> 0 )+
  (F <> 0 ) 
) >= 2
```

Not equal to operator returns boolean(0/1) value against the criteria and you can sum up the results for each column and eliminate the records according to your criteria

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b7c/10)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
select user  
from (
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN a>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE WHEN b>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE WHEN c>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE WHEN d>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE WHEN e>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
       CASE WHEN f>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END chk
FROM   yourtable 
) a 
where chk>=2
```